# Cannot pass data between components in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and am trying to build an app which shuffles football players into two teams and am having difficulty with passing data from one component to another. I have redux and react-redux installed.

My problem is that once 10 names have been inputted (which I am calling `numbersReached`), the button to submit the addPlayers form should be disabled so no more players can be submitted.

I have tried passing a state value, numbersReached, into my AddPlayers component, but it is not being imported correctly - it is showing in console.log as `undefined`.

My code so far:

**'initialState.js'**

```
export const initialState = {
  playersList: [],
  shuffledList: [],
  teamA: [],
  teamB: [],
  numbersReached: false
};

export default initialState;
```

**'src\components\NumbersReached\index.js':**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import NumbersReached from "./NumbersReached";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    numbersReached: state.playersList.length >= 10 // Once state.playersList.length>=10 numbersReached should = true. (10 is for five-a-side)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NumbersReached);
```

**`src\components\NumbersReached\NumbersReached.js`:**

```
import React from "react";

const NumbersReached = ({ numbersReached }) => (
  <div>
    {numbersReached ? "Numbers Reached" : null}
  </div>
);

export default NumbersReached;
```

**'src\components\AddPlayer\index.js':**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import AddPlayer from "./AddPlayer";
import { addPlayer } from "../../data/actions";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    playerName: state.playerName,
    numbersReached: state.numbersReached
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    handleSubmit: (data) => dispatch(addPlayer(data)),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddPlayer);
```

**'src\components\AddPlayer\AddPlayer.js'**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddPlayer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      playerName: props.playerName,
      numbersReached: props.numbersReached
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  };

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ playerName: e.currentTarget.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.handleSubmit({ ...this.state });
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form className="entry-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            placeholder="Enter a player's name"
            className="player-input"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="player-submit"
            disabled={this.state.numbersReached}  // Does not disable the button as this.state.numbersReached is undefined
          >
            Add a player
          </button>
        </form>

      </React.Fragment>
    )

  }
};

export default AddPlayer;
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're likely having is that you're not actually using the value of `numbersReached` in your Redux store. Instead, you're using a `numbersReached` variable inner to your `AddPlayer` component' state.

```
<button
  type="submit"
  className="player-submit"
  disabled={this.state.numbersReached}
>
```

To use the `numbersReached` you defined in `mapStateToProps`, **you should access to `this.props.numbersReached` instead of `this.state.numbersReached`**. The props you inherit from Redux will automatically be updated when the action `addPlayer` is dispatched and the Redux store changes.

The value for your `this.state.numbersReached`, however, won't change unless you call `setState` anywhere in your component. Right now, you're only initializing that value on the constructor:

```
class AddPlayer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      playerName: props.playerName,
      numbersReached: props.numbersReached
    };
  };
}
```

When you do this, you're creating a new `numbersReached` variable in your component' state with the value that the `numbersReached` property in your Redux store had at the time your component is built. As it doesn't have value when the constructor runs, `this.state.numbersReached` is `undefined`.

**Doing `numbersReached: props.numbersReached` does not suscribe you to all of the changes to that property; it just assigns `numbersReached` the value `props.numbersReached` initially had.** That's why, no matter how many players you add, it'll keep been `undefined` even if players have been succesfully added to your store.

Answer (score 0):

you are duplicating redux state at `AddPlayer` state. duplicate state is bad practice and should be avoided. secondly, they are different states, redux'state and react component's state. as it is `this.state.numbersReached` receives the first value on mounting but is not not updated anywehere after.

Also it is weird at your state `playerName: props.playerName`. first, the fact that you dont have at your redux a piece of state called `playerName`. Second, the most revelant, it's a component that create players and adds to your `playersList`. you should better initialize that state as an empty string.

btw, I refactored a little your component to reduce code. if you declare your functions as arrow functions you dont need to bind them at constructor. and you dont need to declare your state at constructor anymore. But if you want to keep the original for consistency, or personal preference go ahead, that's ok also :) .

after all that, your component would look something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddPlayer extends Component {

  state = {
    playerName: ''
  };


  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ playerName: e.currentTarget.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.handleSubmit({ ...this.state });
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form className="entry-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            placeholder="Enter a player's name"
            className="player-input"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="player-submit"
            disabled={this.props.numbersReached}
          >
            Add a player
          </button>
        </form>

      </React.Fragment>
    )

  }
};

export default AddPlayer;
```

a last note, you have numbersReached state, but at your mapStateToProps you set based on a custom function, not on your numbersReached state.

if you want to keep numbersReached state on your redux state, you should handle that logic `state.playersList.length >= 10` at your reducers to update properly there, and not at your mapStateToProps. though you could remove from your redux state `numbersReached` altogether given it's derived from other pieces from your state.